# PNY 32GB Flash drive not working after transferring files?

Tags: 12.04, usb, flash

I just bought a brand new 32GB flash drive (PNY) and I formatted a FAT file system as I wanted to use on both my Ubuntu and Windows machines.

It was working properly after transferring data from a Windows 7 machine and then transferring data from my Ubuntu machine. After doing so it does not recognize on either.

I'm running 12.04, any suggestions? Other than broken, crappy flash drive?

Comment: insert the usb and open up the terminal and run `lsblk` command,then post its output on the ques.

Comment: plz paste the output in pastebin.com and provide the link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1VAGnuPn

Comment: please check that your pendrive detected on windows.

Comment: It does not recognize on Windows either. I checked in the disk management.

Comment: last one,plz post the output of `lsusb` command to pastebin.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YHBnGmch

Comment: Try on another USB jack, then on another computer before you may have to send it back for replacement.

Comment: I've tried every usb jack that I own... a total of 8 of them. I have considered that the drive is DOA.

Comment: I returned the drive as I believe that it was dead on arrival.

Comment: `lsblk` may take a minute or two depending on your OS